# Build a Tensorflow dataset from generator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have 10000 large files.

From each file, we generate large number of training samples.

```
def generate_sample(tokens, id):

    for i in range(len(tokens):
        r = tokens[i]
        x =.. #list
        y= ...# list
        yield(tf.constant([id], tf.int32), tf.constant(x+y, tf.int32), tf.constant([r], tf.int32))

def read_and_process_file(file_name):
    # read file
    tokens, id = read_file(file_name):
   return generate_sample(tokens, id)

def tf_read_and_process_file(file_name):
    return tf.py_function(read_and_process_file, [file_path], [tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32])
file_paths = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('*.pkl.gz')

dataset = file_paths.flat_map(
    lambda file_path: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: tf_read_and_process_file(file_path),
        output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32),
        output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([None,1]), tf.TensorShape([None, 50]), tf.TensorShape([None,1]))
    )
)
# Batch and prefetch
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

for batch in dataset:
    ids, prefixsuffix, targets = batch
```

It throws an error `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_datatype_enum'` near `tf.py_function(read_and_process_file, [file_path], [tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32])`

What is wrong ?